# javascript will not work onload

Tags: javascript

The javascript on the page needs to work onpage load. So I tried adding the document ready function into the code. It doesn't seem to work.

http://janeucreative.com/daddychallenge/bag.html

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {


  function addItem(item) {
        var itemInCart = item.cloneNode(true);
        itemInCart.onclick = function() { removeItem(this); };

        var cart = document.getElementById("cart");
        cart.appendChild(itemInCart);
    }

    function removeItem(item) {
        var itemInItems = item.cloneNode(true);
        itemInItems.onclick = function() { addItem(this); };

        var cart = document.getElementById("cart");
        cart.removeChild(item);
    }
  init();
});</script>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated! I'm very new to javascript and just trying to learn it a step at a time.

Comment: `init()` is not defined. Also you misspelled `bodt` (`body`) in your HTML.

Comment: what do I define it as?

Comment: What are you trying to use it as?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BwjQj/4/ Trying to get this to work in my project, but it needs to work onload, and that's not happening.

Comment: As @Jacedc said, `init()` is a function call, and that function doesn't seem to exist.  Also, rather than copying and pasting stuff, it may be more beneficial in the long run to learn the code and do it yourself.

Comment: What are you trying to load?  There is no content, just functions.  Those functions don't do anything until triggered by an event.  You can put them in the head or body, and they will function the same way.

Comment: @Tim Withers, I'm certainly trying to learn it. I'm trying to get the boxes to end up in the blue section, but no matter what I do on my page they won't work, while they're working in the Fiddle.

Comment: @user2711818 That's because in the fiddle you're not wrapping your function declarations in a `document.ready` Remove that in your webpage and you should fine that everything works well. Also remove your `init()` call, as it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to have your page using a more modern version of jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js" ></script>
```

Then, AFTER linking the jquery, which you have done correctly, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
<script>
function init(toAdd, toRemove){
 addItem(toAdd);
 removeItem(toRemove);
}
function addItem(item) {
        var itemInCart = item.cloneNode(true);
        itemInCart.on("click",function(){removeItem(this);});    
        $("#cart").appendChild(itemInCart);
}
function removeItem(item) {
        var itemInItems = item.cloneNode(true);
        itemInItems.on("click", function(){addItem(this);});    
        $("#cart").removeChild(item);
}
init($("#myAddedItem"), $("myRemovedItem"));
</script>
```

This way, you'll have your functions addItem and removeItem available elsewhere on the page.  You currently seem to have them set up to run only once, from the page initialization.

I'm not sure what you're doing with cloneNode.